How can I generate an cookie with node.js inside an async function
I wrote a server with Node.js (in a .mjs file). I want to program a login. Through an HTML form, using the POST method, a function is called on my server where I in turn call an async function to query my database to see if such a record exists in the database. If there isn't one, an empty array is returned; if there is, my user data is returned from the database. Now, I want to write this information into a cookie in this async function so that I can later access it in another .js file and adjust my HTML accordingly.This is the code for my server.
The hole project code html, js, css u can find under following link. Maybe it will help u/me :)
https://github.com/LukasRandecker/GIS.git
//using import instead of request because it's the modern way 
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import {open} from 'sqlite'; 
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'; 

//because we use ES-Moduls we need following Code, this is AI-generated
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);


//variables
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser()); 
const dbFilePath = "Datenbanken.db";
let customerNumber = 0; 

async function getDataSpices() {
    const db = await open({
        filename: dbFilePath,
        driver: sqlite3.Database,
    });

    const jsonDataAmount = JSON.stringify(await db.all('SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount FROM spices')); //how many spices are there
    const jsonDataSpices = JSON.stringify(await db.all('SELECT * FROM spices')); //all info of every spice
    customerNumber = await db.get('SELECT MAX(customer_number) AS maxCustomerNumber FROM customers');
    customerNumber =customerNumber.maxCustomerNumber; 
    const jsonDataFinal = '{ "arrayAmount":'+jsonDataAmount+',"arraySpices":'+jsonDataSpices+'}';
    fs.writeFile("spices.json", jsonDataFinal, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Fehler beim Schreiben der Datei:', err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Daten erfolgreich in die JSON-Datei geschrieben.');
    });
    await db.close();
}
getDataSpices();


// all the different .???? I need
const extToContentType = {
    '.js': 'text/javascript',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.mov': 'video/quicktime',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.db': 'application/octet-stream',
    '.html': 'text/html',
};

//default Path for the server
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'GIS_Projekt')));

//management login&reg
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.post('/index.html', (req, res) => {
    const rb=req.body; 
    if(req.body.formType == "formLogin"){
        //login management  
        checkUser(rb.mail, rb.password);      
    }else{
        //reg management
        newUser(rb.anrede, rb.first_name, rb.last_name, customerNumber, rb.street, rb.house_number, rb.plz, rb.city, rb.email, rb.password); 
    }
    res.sendFile(path.resolve("index.html")); 
});

async function newUser(salutation, firstName, lastName, customerNumber, street, houseNumber, postalCode, city, email, password) {
    const db = await open({
        filename: dbFilePath,
        driver: sqlite3.Database,
    });
    await db.all("INSERT INTO customers (salutation, first_name, last_name, customer_number, street, house_number, postal_code, city, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",[salutation, firstName, lastName, customerNumber + 1, street, houseNumber, postalCode, city, email, password]);
    await db.close();
}


async function checkUser(email, password){
    const db = await open({
        filename: dbFilePath,
        driver: sqlite3.Database,
    });

    //write database inforamtion that I go from the email and password
    const person = await db.all('SELECT salutation, first_name, last_name, customer_number, street, house_number, postal_code, city, email FROM customers WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', [email, password]); 
    //HERE I WANT TO GENERATE THE COOKIE WITH THE NAME "user" and the value of person. 
    await db.close(); 
    
}




//server structure onload/navigation
app.use((req, res) => {
    //if I just type localhost:3000 I dont enter server error, I will open the index.html, if I want special page I can do this 
    let filePath = '.'+req.url; 
    if(filePath==="./")
        filePath="./index.html"; 
    else
        filePath = './'+req.url; 

    //witch .??? do I have/use 
    const extname = path.extname(filePath);
    const contentType = extToContentType[extname] || 'text/html';


    //AI-generated
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                // page not found
                fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'GIS_Projekt', '404.html'), (err, content) => {
                    res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            } else {
                // server error
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end('Sorry, ein interner Serverfehler ist aufgetreten.');
            }
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
});

//start the Server
const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server läuft auf Port ${PORT}`);
});


I know there is the following import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser' and I tryed to use it but I coun't find out whats the problem is and why it doesn't work. For example I tryed res.cookie(key value)(I passed res as an parameter for the function) but I doesnt work. Does someone know how I can solve this type of Problem? Or does someone know an better way?

Cookies are typically set on the response object, so It should be res.cookie(key, value, options). Not reg(maybe you tried to use req?).

okay yeah I mistyped,I guess. Now it's working, hahaha so bad from me. Thanks for ur help <3
